# Accessing predicates from included prolog file

Tags: prolog

New to writing prolog.I wanted to know how can i access the predicates from an already included prolog file.I want to get the 1rst String of every predicate called work.The file that i included is called working.pl.I included it this way :  `:- [working.pl].`. The code of the working.pl file looks like this:

```
work('Firefighter',['George','Mike','Angel']).
work('Doctor',['Mary','Mikel]).
work('Fisherman',['John','Pat]).
```

I expect to get `['Firefighter','Doctor','Fisherman'].`

Comment: Something like `bagof(Person,work(Person,_),People)`.

Comment: Thanks that seems to work and because i want the possible duplicates , i find out that i can use findall.

Comment: You should post your code as an answer and pick up some more points.